# Typescript/React : Passing single data from transferFilterValues.currency table to search component that will filter currencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to access the transferFilterValues and filter table by currencies by the hardcoded options values

Pretty unsure where to even start any help would be appreciated really need second pair of fresh eyes

Seems to need something involving query keys https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys but I am unfamiliar with them.

Starting code

```
export default function CurrenciesTable() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const [transferFilterValues, setTransferFilterValues] = React.useState({
    status: '',
    currency: 'USD',
  })
 
  function handleTransferFilter(event) {
    setTransferFilterValues({
      ...transferFilterValues,
      currency: event.target.value,
    })
  }

  return (
    <Stack spacing={2}>
      <Typography variant="h3">Conversion</Typography>
      <ConvertHistoryTable filterValues={convertFilterValues} />
      <Typography variant="h3">Transfer</Typography>
      <CurrencySelector
        label="Currency"
        options={['USD', 'AUD']}
        selectedOption={transferFilterValues.currency}
        handleSelect={handleTransferFilter}
      />
      <TransferHistoryTable filterValues={transferFilterValues} />
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

```
//TansferHistoryTable.tsx
import React from 'react'

import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell'
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow'
import ChartContainer from 'components/ChartContainer/ChartContainer'
import QueryHolder from 'components/ContentWrapper/QueryHolder'
import StaticTable from 'components/Table/StaticTable'
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton'
import PreviewIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Preview'
import TableNumericCell from 'components/Table/TableNumericCell'
//  hooks
import { useGetTransferRecord } from 'hooks/transaction'
import { TransferRecordData, TransferType } from '../types/Transaction'

type Props = {
  filterValues?: any
  maxHeight?: number
  small?: boolean
}

export default function TransferHistoryTable({ filterValues, maxHeight, small }: Props) {
  //  query below should receive filterValues and refetch base on these values
  const queryRes = useGetTransferRecord(filterValues?.currency)

  const records: TransferRecordData[] = queryRes.isSuccess ? queryRes.data.data : []

  return (
    <ChartContainer>
      <QueryHolder queryRes={queryRes}>
        <StaticTable
          small={small}
          maxHeight={maxHeight}
          fieldRows={['Number', 'Type', 'Currency', 'Amount', 'Fee', 'Status', 'Details']}
          valueRows={records.map((item: TransferRecordData) => getTableItem(item, item.uuid))}
        />
      </QueryHolder>
    </ChartContainer>
  )
}

function getTableItem(item: TransferRecordData, key: string) {
  return (
    <TableRow key={key}>
      <TableCell>{item.refNum}</TableCell>
      <TypeCell type={item.type} />
      <TableCell>{item.currencyCode}</TableCell>
      <TableNumericCell value={item.amount} />
      <TableCell>{item.collectionFee}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{item.status}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <IconButton>
          <PreviewIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  )
}

type TypeCellProps = {
  type: TransferType
}

const TypeCell = ({ type }: TypeCellProps) => {
  if (type === TransferType.DEPOSIT) {
    return <TableCell sx={{ color: 'success.main' }}>{type}</TableCell>
  } else {
    return <TableCell sx={{ color: 'error.main' }}>{type}</TableCell>
  }
}
```

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'

import useUser from 'hooks/user'
//  apis
import { transactionAPI } from 'apis'
import { useSelectedAccount } from './account'

export function useGetTransferRecord(currency?: string) {
  const { user } = useUser()
  const { account } = useSelectedAccount()

  return useQuery(
    ['get-filtered-transfer'],
    () => user && account && transactionAPI.getAllTransferByAccountUuid(account.uuid, currency)
  )
}
```

[image: Search DropDown]

Comment: `handleTransferFilter` is a function you are trying to call `filter` on a function while it only exists in arrays. You should be doing `transferFilterValues.filter(.....`

Comment: Attempted your edit same error sadly

Comment: You are trying to filter the table rows, right? You have to use the `.filter` on its data, and filter it base on `transferFilterValues`, probably something like: `myTableRows.filter(row => row.currency === transferFilterValues.currency)`. But I'm not sure how your `TransferHistoryTable` works, can you show the component code?

Comment: Have added the TransferHistoryTable components code to the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up being

```
 return useQuery(
    ['get-filtered-transfer', currency],
```

Passing currency to the API call, and then you can chain on other calls
If someone is able to provide an in-depth answer that would be great otherwise ill come back and edit this answer when I have time